# mySQL query working in PHPmyAdmin but not in PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue with one of my queries. I have a query that displays a list of contacts from a database for a specific account. When I put this into phpMyAdmin I get 1 result as expected. When I try to execute the same query from php I am getting no results.

```
<?php 
            $getContacts="SELECT * FROM `accountContactDetails` where acNo='ZZZ001' ";
            $contactsResults = $conn->query($getContacts);

                if ($contactsResults->num_rows > 0) { 

                    while($contact = $contactsResults->fetch_assoc()) { 

                        echo $contact['email'];

                     } 

                 }  

                 var_dump($contactsResults); 
                 echo $getContacts; 
        ?>
```

The line at the bottom with the vardump and query excecuted outputs this.. 
bool(false) SELECT * FROM `accountContactDetails` where acNo='ZZZ001'

When I copy the exact same query into PHPmyAdmin I get one result. This is not to do with the database connection as this works in the file both before and after this query.

Can anyone think why this might not be returning a result? Any help with this is much appreciated!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: here we go with yet another unclear post.

Comment: Not sure how it is unclear? But thanks for your creative input.

Comment: Do other queries work as expected? Have you tried stripping down your code or your query to confirm if a more simple version works? What happens if you var_dump the contents of `$contact` in the while loop? It's not so much unclear so much as unnecessarily complex. Do you need to do the mixed PHP/HTML for this question? Have you tried testing without all that other stuff in the way?

Comment: Yes all the queries on the page work fine. I have even removed the variable from the query string and just used the specific account number i am testing out. I will test it out without the html in the middle to see if that is causing the issue. Thanks for answering!

Comment: I have edited it to remove the HTML from it and also removed the variable from the query and it still not giving any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying your database in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT * FROM myDatabase.accountContactDetails WHERE acNo='$acNo';
```

This should also be a prepared statement, as they were saying above:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM myDatabase.accountContactDetails WHERE acNo=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $acNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
$getContacts="SELECT * FROM accountContactDetails where acNo = {$acNo}";
```

Comment: It turns out I created the table in the wrong database. Such a stupid mistake (it's the end of a long day for me) Apologies for wasting your time.